# Calling super for cellForRowAtIndexPath in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I would greatly appreciate it someone could help me with the syntax for calling `super` to get the `UITableViewCell` from within `func tableView (tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)`.  This is a static table.

```
override func tableView (tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
//  The Objective-C code is: UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
var cell = super.??
}
```

I have tried and tried, but cannot seem to get the correct syntax for doing this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks VERY much!  I thought that I tried that (about million times)!!

Comment: May I ask what does calling super do? I am seeing this code in the HomeKit app from Apple and I am not understanding this code. Usually we dequeue it and modify the cell in ways we want, but calling super?

Comment: @huggie This only applies to static table views defined in interface builder. Calling super will give you the static cell that's been set up in the xib file.

Answer (score 3):

Update for Swift 3:

```
var cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

What it worked to me was.

```
let cell = someController.tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: item, section: 0) as IndexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 and ios 10+

1. Create outlets.
2. oneCellOutlets.IsHidden = true

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

   if cell.isHidden == true
   {
       return 0
   }
   else{
       return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
   }
   }
   ```